# Campo do tipo type="email" despreza o ValidationMessageFor asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html5

Quando se usa este tipo de campo ele despreza `ValidationMessageFor`?

**Na classe**

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o seu login.")]
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "Por favor insira ...")]
[StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "O número de caracteres permitidos é 50.")]
public string login { get; set; }
```

**No formulário**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.login, new { placeholder = 
     @Projeto.WEB.Celular.Resources.HomeText.txtRecuperaSenha, 
     @class = "form-control input-lg", type = "email", })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.login)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acredito que não seja isso, veja que tenho o DataType

Comment: Eu fiz o exemplo, veja na minha pergunta que está seguindo o modelo, mesmo assim ele usa o padrão em inglês

Comment: A mensagem não está de acordo com  [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "Por favor insira ...")]

Comment: sim, mais acredito que não tenha problema, porque o Resources tem apenas o texto que fica dentro do input

Comment: ok, mesmo assim eu agradeço